# Will notify interrupt the sleeping thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, producer-consumer, java.util.concurrent

I have implemented Classical example of producer and consumer. Here producer will sleep for **10 seconds** after producing `value = 0` [will not go waiting for the state because of queue size is one which is less than 10 ]. And the consumer will consume `value =0` and notify the producer will sleep for **one second**.

*So My question is that why Notify by the consumer is not interrupting producer thread and print `Producer Exception cached`.*

The output of the following program is like:

```
Producer add value=0
Consumer consumes value=0
```

*(wait for 10 seconds)*

```
Producer add value=1
Consumer consumes value=1
```

*(wait for 10 seconds)*

```
Producer add value=2
Consumer consumes value=2
```

Classical Example of Producer and consumer.

```
public class ClassicalProducerConsumer{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Buffer  buffer = new Buffer(3);
        Thread producer = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    int value = 0;
                    while (true) {
                        buffer.add(value);
                        value++;
                        Thread.sleep(10000); // Make producer wait for 10 seconds.
                    }
                }catch (Exception ex){
                    System.out.println("Producer Exception cached");
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        Thread consumer = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    while (true) {
                        int value = buffer.poll();
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    }
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    System.out.println("Consumer Exception cached");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        producer.start();
        consumer.start();
    }
}

class Buffer{
    Queue<Integer> queue;
    int size;

    public Buffer(int size) {
        this.size = size;
        queue = new LinkedList<>();
    }
    public void add(int value) throws InterruptedException {
        synchronized (this){
            while (queue.size() >=size){
                wait();
            }
            System.out.println("Producer add value="+ value);
            queue.add(value);
            notify();
        }
    }
    public int poll() throws InterruptedException {
        synchronized (this){
            while (queue.size()==0){
                wait();
            }
            int value = queue.poll();
            System.out.println("Consumer consumes value="+ value);
            notify();
            return value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `notify` and `interrupt` are two different mechanisms.

Comment: Because it's possible to have multiple threads waiting on a producer/consumer problem like this, I usually prefer to use `notifyAll()` just to make sure any possible thread does not get starved or missed.

Answer (score 0):

As @RealSkeptic mentioned `notify()` has nothing to do with interruption. Call `interrupt()` on a thread you want to interrupt instead. Then any blocking method in this thread will return control by throwing **Interrupted exception**. It is advisable to restore the interrupted state of the thread by calling `Thread.currentThread().interrupt()` in the catch block.

Comment: There's no need to restore the interrupted state. It's an oft-repeated piece of advice that serves no purpose.

Comment: @JohnKugelman what if I need to examine whether the thread was interrupted or not later in the code?

Comment: @JohnKugelman Brian Goetz in his book "Concurrency in practice" says that there are two ways to deal with interruption - propagate it higher up the stack or restore it.  Since Thread's 'run()' does not allow propagation we need to restore it then

Comment: You'll know based on whether you're in the `try` or the `catch` block. There's no need for a flag to tell you. If you catch an `SQLException` or a `NumberFormatException` you use code flow to tell whether you're in an exceptional state; you don't need to set or check a flag.

Comment: The code you write is the only code that cares about the status. Once you've received the `InterruptedException` you've been notified of the interruption. There's nobody else you need to communicate that information to. The flag is only there for you in the event you are doing some long-running task without calling a blocking function like `sleep()`. There is no need to re-call `interrupt()`, nor is there any reason to call `isInterrupted()`. It is safe to handle `InterruptedException`s and/or check `interrupted()` and let the flag be cleared.

Comment: @JohnKugelman ok, I see your point and agree with you but consider one particular scenario: the Thread's `run()` calls a method (let's call it `calculate()`) which should internally implement it's interruption policy and therefore catch Interrupted exception for any reasons (for instance: to log particular local variables in this method). Here `run()` knows nothing about interruption. But it might need to know. Of course you can rethrow Interrupted exception from the catch block of `calculate()` but restoring the interruption status can be a good way to go too

Comment: In that scenario I would document that `calculate()` is a slow/blocking method that can be interrupted in its Javadoc and would declare it with `throws InterruptedException`.

Comment: I don't mean to be argumentative, and really my thoughts on interruptions deserve their own blog post, or maybe a standalone Q&A. I think the API documentation does a poor job of explaining how interrupts should be used and what they're for. You *can* preserve the interrupt flag and you *can* check it without clearing it, but neither are necessary. The API documentation ought to advocate for simply catching `InterruptedException` and in rare cases checking `interrupted()`. It should discourage calling `isInterrupted()`. Clearing the interrupt flag is normal and expected.

Comment: Most importantly, it should explain who actually calls `interrupt()` and triggers interruptions: it's always your own code! Interruptions don't happen unless you yourself the application writer cause them to happen. If you don't call `interrupt()` yourself your threads will never be interrupted. It's an API flaw that `InterruptedException` is a checked exception. Being required to catch it any time we call `sleep()` is a mistake. Most of us don't interrupt our own threads; our sleep calls are never interrupted. We're required to handle exceptions that never happen! Ugh.